# How to auto-accept a friend-request in buddypress based on user meta

Tags: buddypress

I’m still getting my head around buddypress, so far so good but I’ve hit a snag where I want certain users who are flagged as an ‘expert’ to automatically accept any friend requests people make.

I’ve found a couple of functions related to this but I think I’m missing something that would make this simpler such as setting a constant or overriding part of the $bp global…

What I have so far is the following:

```
function bp_auto_accept_friend_request( $friendship_id, $friendship_initiator_id, $friendship_friend_id ) {
    if ( is_user_expert( $friendship_friend_id ) ) {
        // force add
        friends_accept_friendship( $friendship_id );
        friends_add_friend( $friendship_initiator_id, $friendship_friend_id, true );
    }
}
add_action('friends_friendship_requested', 'bp_auto_accept_friend_request', 200, 3);
```

Can anyone tell me where I should be looking to make this nice and seamless just as if the main settings were set to bypass the request process please?

Comment: Had no joy with this so far. There's no straight forward way to do it it would seem so I need the help of a BP expert.

Comment: I'm not sure but i think you got the functions in a worng order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### UPDATE

try this

```
function bp_auto_accept_friend_request( $friendship_id, $friendship_initiator_id, $friendship_friend_id ) {
        $friendship_status = BP_Friends_Friendship::check_is_friend( $friendship_initiator_id, $friendship_friend_id );
        if ( 'not_friends' == $friendship_status ) {
            if ( is_user_expert( $friendship_friend_id ) ) {
            // force add
            friends_add_friend( $friendship_initiator_id, $friendship_friend_id, true );
            friends_accept_friendship( $friendship_id );
        }
        }
    }
    add_action('friends_friendship_requested', 'bp_auto_accept_friend_request', 200, 3);
```

this way we only call friends_add_friend function with $force = true if they are not friends yet.

Comment: That doesn't do the job I'm afraid. The friendship status and the total friends count don't seem to be updating.

Comment: are you sure that is_user_expert is working?
and i think i have a lead for you this hook 'friends_friendship_requested'
is called after , friends_add_friend function is done, and with this code we are creating an infi loop.
so i'll dig some more.

Comment: i added an update

Comment: the is_user_expert function works fine. It confused me that the friends_add_friend function was run just to create the friendship record, not when the friendship was confirmed. I'll try out your method.

Comment: Let me know how if go's ,I have another angle

Comment: This worked for me if I remove the check for if they are already friends. Remove "if ( 'not_friends' == $friendship_status ) {"

This was failing so the entire block of code failed.